# Simplifying expression with square root of square roots

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following expression

```
 FullSimplify[
 Sqrt[1 + (-1 + a) (-1 + b) + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)]] - Sqrt[
  2 + a (-1 + b) - 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)] - b]]
```

Where $a\ge1$ and $b\ge1$. I know the answer should be $\sqrt{(1-a)(1-b)}$. However, $Mathematica$ doesn't solve this expression this way. How can one resolve this?

Comment: `Reduce[{Sqrt[1 + (-1 + a) (-1 + b) + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)]] - 
    Sqrt[2 + a (-1 + b) - 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)] - b] == 
   Sqrt[(a - 1) (b - 1)], a > 1, b > 1}]` says this is `True` only when `a == (3 + b)/(-1 + b)`

Comment: They don't seem to match at, for example, `a -> 1.23, b -> 2.34`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 expr1 = Sqrt[1 + (-1 + a) (-1 + b) + 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)]] - 
      Sqrt[2 + a (-1 + b) - 2 Sqrt[(-1 + a) (-1 + b)] - b];
expr2 = Simplify[expr1 /. {a -> x + 1, b -> y + 1}, {x > 0, y > 0}]

(*  -Sqrt[1 + x y - 2 Sqrt[x y]] + Sqrt[1 + x y + 2 Sqrt[x y]]  *)
```

Then

```
expr3=Simplify[expr2 /. x*y -> z^2, z > 0]
```

[image]

Now

```
expr3 /. z -> (a - 1) (b - 1)
```

yields

[image]

Have fun!